# Convert ENUM to DTO

Tags: java

I have this Java ENUM which I would like to convert to DTO:

```
public enum TicketStatus {
    N("new", "New"),
    A("assigned", "Assigned"),
    IP("in_progress", "In-progress"),
    C("closed", "Closed");

    private String shortName;

    private String fullName;

    TicketStatus(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

I want to convert the EMUM to a list of items:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class TicketStatusTypesDTO {

    private String code;

    private String name;
}
```

`code` should be mapped as `shortName` and `name` as `fullName`. How this can be converted?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
List<TicketStatusTypesDTO> list = null;
for (TicketStatus status : TicketStatus.values()) {
   list.add(new TicketStatusTypesDTO(status.getShortName(), status.getShortName()));
}
```

How I can improve the code by using stream? Something like this:

```
TicketStatus.values().entrySet().stream()
            .map(g -> new TicketStatusTypesDTO(g.getKey(), g.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why use a DTO? You don't want annotations in your enum?

Comment: It's unclear what part JSON has to play in this. Are you just trying to convert 4 enum constants into corresponding `TicketStatusTypesDTO` objects? Or are you trying to parse some JSON content into `TicketStatusTypesDTO` objects?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to convert 4 enum constants into corresponding TicketStatusTypesDTO objects.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with JSON and the Jackson annotations in your post?

Comment: I think yes. How I can achieve this?

Comment: It’s still not clear what you want to achieve, especially considering the answer you accepted. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonProperty` for that.

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class TicketStatusTypesDTO {    
        @JsonProperty("shortName")
        private String code;
    
        @JsonProperty("fullName")
        private String name;
    }
```

You could also do the mapping with the constructor like so:

```
@JsonCreator
public TicketStatusTypesDTO (
  @JsonProperty("shortName") String code, 
  @JsonProperty("fullName") String name) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
}
```

More on this here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: Can you extend the code a bit more please?

Comment: like this @PeterPenzov?

Comment: How I can get the ENUM and convert it as a list?

Comment: Maybe like this: `.entrySet().stream()
                .map(g -> new TicketStatusTypesDTO(g.getKey(), g.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: `Arrays.asList(TicketStatus.values());`

Comment: Is it possible to map the value without `@JsonProperty(...)`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I don't know. You could also change the names in the constructor using `@JsonCreator` together with `@JsonProperty`. See my edited answer.

Comment: In my case I need to convert 4 enum constants into corresponding TicketStatusTypesDTO objects.

Comment: @PeterPenzov How about this: `Arrays.asList(TicketStatus.values()).forEach(enumConstant -> //your conversioncode here)`

Comment: Can you show me the full code, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov i'm not going to write the program for you. Just make a `constructor` for `TicketStatusTypesDTO` that has the argument `TicketStatus ticketStatusConstant`. Use this constructor to initialize the fields and replace the `enumConstant -> //your conversioncode` part with either `enumConstant -> new TicketStatusTypesDTO(enumConstant)` or with `TicketStatusTypesDTO::new`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need @JsonProperty annotation at all, I have tested it without it and it works.

Enum:

```
public enum TicketStatus {
    N("new", "New"),
    A("assigned", "Assigned"),
    IP("in_progress", "In-progress"),
    C("closed", "Closed");

    private String shortName;

    private String fullName;

    TicketStatus(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class TicketStatusTypesDTO {
    private String code;
    private String name;
}
```

You can use:

```
Stream.of(TicketStatus.values()).map(
                ticketStatusType -> new TicketStatusTypesDTO(
                        ticketStatusType.getShortName(),
                        ticketStatusType.getFullName()
                )
        ).toList();
```

This will return List which you can use in your service as:

```
@Override
    public List<TicketStatusTypesDTO> getAllTicketStatusTypes() {
        return Stream.of(TicketStatus.values()).map(
                ticketStatusType -> new TicketStatusTypesDTO(
                        ticketStatusType.getShortName(),
                        ticketStatusType.getFullName()
                )
        ).toList();
    }
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/statuses")
    public ResponseEntity<List<TicketStatusTypesDTO>> getAllTicketStatusTypes() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.ticketService.getAllTicketStatusTypes(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "shortName": "new",
        "fullName": "New"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "assigned",
        "fullName": "Assigned"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "in_progress",
        "fullName": "In-progress"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "closed",
        "fullName": "Closed"
    }
]
```